# send multiple data with $.ajax() jquery using selectors as well

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

is there a way to send data with ajax mixing selector and independent data like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"here.php",
    data: $("#form :input")+"&"+"id="+id,
    type:"POST",
    success: function(res){
        $("#something").html(res);
    }
})
```

I know I can send data with either one of them alone, but it would help me so much to know if this is possible. Any help and recommendations will be appreciated.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: `data: $("#form :input")+"&"+"id="+id,` What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: No, you can't send a jquery object over ajax. How would you expect the server to interpret a jquery object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `serialize()` (*i suppose you are trying to send all input values inside your `#form`*)

```
 data: $("#form :input").serialize() + "&" + "id=" + id,
```

Comment: Wow you man saved me few hours of headache. That's the answer and it works perfectly, thank you so so much.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to send a selector, you want to send the value of inputs within the form.

```
var data = $("#form").serialize();
data += "&id=" + id;
$.ajax({
    url: "foo.php",
    data: data,
    ...
});
```